# ERRORS: inside.UserProfile.user: (fields.E301) Field defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-models, model

I am a beginner in Django.
I am trying to build an app with user authentication. However I want extra fields like country and phone number, and I don't want any username field (I want the phone number to act as the username), so I built a custom user class.
There are questions that have already been asked that have the same error, but they are not exactly relevant to my use case and the solutions don't work for me.

models.py:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from django.conf import settings

from django_countries.fields import CountryField

# Create your models here.

class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.DO_NOTHING)

    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length = 16, unique = True, blank = False, null = False)
    country = CountryField()
    uid = models.UUIDField(
        default = None,
        blank = True,
        null = True,
        unique = True,
    )
    USERNAME_FIELD = "uid"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['phone_number', 'country']
```

forms.py:

```py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import UserProfile

from django_countries.fields import CountryField


# Create your forms here..

class NewUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    phone_number = forms.RegexField(max_length = 16, regex = r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$')
    country = CountryField()
    
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ("phone_number", "country", "password1", "password2")
        
    def save(self, commit = True):
        user = super(NewUserForm, self).save(commit = False)
        user.phone_number = self.cleaned_data['phone_number']
        user.username = user.phone_number
        user.country = self.cleaned_data['country']
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

settings.py:

```py
"""
Django settings for app project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.0.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-pu46*rr%pr(^utidu^bob6o#f*s4w5ig#$fmc$f@ga45+p2wzc'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'inside.apps.InsideConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'crispy_forms',
    'phonenumber_field',
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'inside.UserProfile'

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'app.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'app.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Django throws this error:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kanav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Kanav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kanav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kanav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 124, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\Kanav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 488, in check
    raise SystemCheckError(msg)
django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
inside.UserProfile.user: (fields.E301) Field defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out.
        HINT: Update the relation to point at 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL'.

System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining a relationship to the default `User` Model, which you are not using anymore as you have created a custom user model. Remove the `one_to_one_field` to avoid this error
And to further errors you have to create a custom `manager`

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from django.conf import settings

from django_countries.fields import CountryField

# Create your models here.

class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser):
    # Remove this as you no longer using the default User Model.
    # user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.DO_NOTHING)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length = 16, unique = True, blank = False, null = False)
    country = CountryField()
    # As you are using UID as your username field 
    # it is not safe to make it blank and null true 
    uid = models.UUIDField(
        default = None,
        blank = True,
        null = True,
        unique = True,
    )
    USERNAME_FIELD = "uid"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['phone_number', 'country']
    # Create your custom user manager 
    objects = YOUR_CUSTOM_USER_MANAGER()
```

Note: As you are using uid as your username field, you have to write a custom authentication backend so that you can use the phone number to authenticate the user, otherwise you have to use the phone number as a username field if you don't want to create a custom authentication backend.

Comment: I had added that relationship so that my class would be exactly like django's user class with few tweaks. Now when I run I get a new error `django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: inside_userprofile.password` because this was not defined in my class but when I do with that relationship it works because django's username class has the password column and I am inheriting all of that from django's user class I guess

Comment: But custom models don't work that way, if you want to create a custom model, you have to write your own model manager, to avoid this error

Comment: how do i write a model manager? what would my model manager look like in this case? can you link a stackoverflow answer or useful article please, or explain it? thanks.

Comment: https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/how-to-create-a-custom-django-user-model 

You can follow this tutorial to create a custom user model, also I have a codebase where I implemented a custom user model

https://github.com/khan-asfi-reza/ChatAPI - Check the `Account` Directory, and `models.py` and `manager.py` file

Comment: Thank you so much! I accepted your answer! And also, about setting uid as my username field, would it work if I just removed the uid field and wrote `USERNAME_FIELD = "phone_number"`?

Comment: If you want to use phone_number as username then it will work, make sure you use `unique=True` to avoid complexity and any uncertain error